# Javascript/Typescipt : Array count issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, count

trying to generate a table report and display in table form, count of each rating based on date. Rating is based on 5. I have the object

```
const surveyReport = [
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "First Comment"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "3 star Comment"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "3 Star Rating"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "2"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "2 Star Rating"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-31T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "New UI looks good"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-31T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "star rating 4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-31T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "1"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Difficult to Navigate"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-31T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Okay UI"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "2"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "two Star Rating"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Easy payment site"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-15T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-03T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "5"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Awesome"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-03T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "PS rocks"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-02T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "three Star Rating"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-02T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "5"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Experian Rocks"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-01T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "4 Star Rating"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-01T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Easy Payment Plan set up"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-29T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Nice UI"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-29T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "5"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Best UI"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-27T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "2"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "NOT UI FRIENDLY"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-27T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Beautiful Colors"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-27T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Colors are just OK"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-31T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Nice Colors"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-01T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-02T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-03T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-11-04T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "3 stars"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "SurveyDateTaken": "2022-10-31T00:00:00",
        "SurveyAnswers": [
            {
                "Title": "Star Rating",
                "AnswerKey": "3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Feedback",
                "AnswerKey": "Need Chat Support"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

trying to generate a table, each row in the table should have cells with Table head: Date, 1 rating (count), 2 rating (count), 3 rating (count), 4 rating (count), 5 rating (count)

```
const group = (arr) => 
   Object.entries(arr.reduce((acc, { SurveyDateTaken, SurveyAnswers }) => {
      const [{ AnswerKey }] = SurveyAnswers;
      console.error('Ans', AnswerKey);
      (acc[SurveyDateTaken] || (acc[SurveyDateTaken] = [])).push(AnswerKey);
      return acc;
   }, {})).map<{SurveyDateTaken: string, Ratings: string[]}>(([date, rating ]) => ({ SurveyDateTaken: moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'), Ratings: (rating as string[]) }));
   
const res = group(surveyReport);

const ratingCount = res.map(day => {
  const ratingCountObj = day.Ratings.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[cur] ? acc[cur]++: acc[cur] = 1, acc), {});
  return {
    date: day.SurveyDateTaken,
    ratingCounts: Object.values(ratingCountObj)
  }
}
);

const renderCountRows = ( ratingCountPerDay ) => {

  return (
    <>
      <TableCell>{ratingCountPerDay.date}</TableCell>
      {ratingCountPerDay.ratingCounts.map((ratingCount) => (
        <TableCell style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>{ratingCount}</TableCell>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

HTML:

```
<>
          <div> Rating Report </div>
          <>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <div className={classes.paperContainer}>
              <TableContainer>
                <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="customized table">
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                      <StyledTableCell>Date Submitted</StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell align="right">1 Star</StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell align="right">2 Star</StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell align="right">3 Star</StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell align="right">4 Star</StyledTableCell>
                      <StyledTableCell align="right">5 Star</StyledTableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <TableBody>
                    {ratingCount.map(rc => (
                      <TableRow key={rc.date}>
                        {renderCountRows(rc)}
                      </TableRow>
                    ) )}
                  </TableBody>
                </Table>
              </TableContainer>
            </div>
          </Paper>
        </>
        </>
```

the count of each star rating is incorrect. Need help where I'm going wrong

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty quick fix this one. You're using `ratingCount` as an array, but you're not including the zero counts which is a problem. You're counting the ratings correctly, but you need to include the zero counts in the array to make sure the counts are in the correct position. Something like this would do the job:

```js
const ratingCount = res.map(day => {
  const ratingCountObj = day.Ratings.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      acc[cur]++
      return acc
    },
    {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0}
  );
  return {
    date: day.SurveyDateTaken,
    ratingCounts: Object.values(ratingCountObj),
  };
});
```

Personally I'd do it with an array instead, something like:

```js
const ratingCount = res.map(day => {
  const ratingCounts = day.Ratings.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      acc[cur-1]++
      return acc
    },
    [0,0,0,0,0]
  );
  return {
    date: day.SurveyDateTaken,
    ratingCounts: ratingCounts,
  };
});
```

but either way should solve your immediate problem.

One quick comment on types too - you're typing `Ratings` as a string array. This may be on purpose, but just pointing it out in case this causes you issues elsewhere. They seem more like numbers to me.